# What tool or special bit do I need to remove this (will add the name later when I know it :-) )

Tags: tools

I do not know the name of the hardware that I need to remove, please see the picture below. The brass like colored piece is stuck there really well. I have tried with a screwdriver, I pushed with a hammer...no results.

I need to remove it and to somehow recover the functionality of this casement window operator which stopped functioning because this thing was loose and it was coming out. I guess the thread is gone

[image]

Edit: it seems that this is what I need (Universal Adjustable Angle Grinder Pin Wrench)
[image]

Edit2: they are quite expensive, here isone that you can make yourself, provided that you have the right size for the rod

[image]

Comment: Ate you sure it is meant to come out like a screw at all?

Comment: yes because it used to. Because the thread is gone it did not went straight and that is the reason why it is stucked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tool you need is called a pin spanner

http://www.mcmaster.com/#pin-spanner-wrenches/=12f7p7g

Comment: let's keep the conversation civil, please.